# Polling repository with coroutine channels

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I'm playing with coroutine channels and I wanted to implemented a polling test project. The idea is that a viewmodel will listen for data from a repository that polls an endpoint repeatedly.

When I pass a coroutineScope to the repository, the polling works, however when I create a new coroutineSCope in the repository, I see the data being injected into the channel, but it's not received on the viewmodel.

So this works:

```
class PollingViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val counter = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "uninitialized" }

    private val repository = Repository()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val channel = repository.poll(this /* scope */)
            channel.consumeEach {
                Log.d("foo", "Viewmodel received [$it]")
                counter.postValue(it.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}

class Repository {

    private var startValue = 0

    suspend fun poll(coroutineScope: CoroutineScope) =
        coroutineScope.produce(capacity = Channel.CONFLATED) {
            while (true) {
                Log.d("foo", "Sending value [$startValue]")
                send(startValue++)
                delay(POLLING_PERIOD_MILLIS)
            }
        }

    companion object {
        private const val POLLING_PERIOD_MILLIS = 1000L
    }
}
```

But this does not (viewmodel does not receive anything):

```
class PollingViewModel : ViewModel() {

    val counter = MutableLiveData<String>().apply { value = "uninitialized" }

    private val repository = Repository()

    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.poll().consumeEach {
                Log.d("foo", "Viewmodel received [$it]")
                counter.postValue(it.toString())
            }
        }
    }
}

class Repository {

    private var startValue = 0

    suspend fun poll() = coroutineScope {
        produce(capacity = Channel.CONFLATED) {
            while (true) {
                Log.d("foo", "Sending value [$startValue]")
                send(startValue++)
                delay(POLLING_PERIOD_MILLIS)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val POLLING_PERIOD_MILLIS = 1000L
    }
}
```

What is the issue with creating a coroutineScope at the repository level?

Answer (score -1):

Looks like the solution is to create a new CoroutineContext in the repository:

```
class Repository {

    private var startValue = 0
    private val context: CoroutineContext by lazy(LazyThreadSafetyMode.NONE) {
        Job() + Dispatchers.IO
    }

    suspend fun poll(): ReceiveChannel<Int> = coroutineScope {
        produce(
            context = context,
            capacity = Channel.CONFLATED
        ) {
            while (true) {
                send(startValue++)
                delay(POLLING_PERIOD_MILLIS)
            }
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val POLLING_PERIOD_MILLIS = 1000L
    }
}
```